# Renewing provisioning profile for private app

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, renewal

I have an app that is only available to certain users, through the enterprise distribution program. Basically, users get their download link from us and they can download the app there with their device.

The provisioning profile (not certificate) expired lastweek, so i simply clicked "Generate" and it created a new one with the same name. After downloading it, I saw it at the top of my provisioning profiles list and added it in my project in xcode under the "distribution/release" lines. I re-archived and uploaded the .ipa and technically, users shouldn't notice any difference. I was very happy with that until someone couldn't start the app anymore (the very next day) and i'd like to make sure that :

- I used the correct stepts to renew my provisioning profile
- It might be related
- I havent missed something

Could anyone enlighten me about this? Did i do something wrong?

Crashlytics doesn't report ANY crash whatsoever (not in the last month at least) so i'm really unsure where to look, and since this profile is the only change in the last month, it could only be that.
But i can't see why.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that provisioning profiles expire on the device too.. So the probably need to re-download the app from the new link you can provide them.

Comment: Do you think users should all re-download the app?

Comment: I do, but I'm not used to working with the enterprise distribution program..